# As3 sprite rotationX and rotationY

Tags: actionscript-3, rotation

I have a bit problem with rotationX and rotationY.

It's cool if i just do a roationX and rotaionY below

```
_eventParent.rotationY =_differentX; 
_eventParent.rotationX =_differentY;
```

However once i have assign a mouse move to the _eventParent. The roationX and roationY change perspectively while the mouse is moving. so instead the item remain the same size. it increase and decrease size prospectively. any idea why is it doing this? is there a possibility to stop this behavior?

Thanks

Please find the image below.

[image]

Comment: Post more code and maybe a swf showing the problem.

Comment: @JonatanHedborg thanks jonatan i have uploaded a image of the situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perspective allows part of your shape to look closer to you than other parts. The problem is that perspective has a center, or "vanishing point" and by default, it is fixed. As you move your shape farther away from the vanishing point, the perspective changes, causing your shape to widen or narrow.

You can fix this by updating the vanishing point so that it is always at the same coordinates as your shape. Since the shape will always be at the vanishing point, the perspective shouldn't change.

To do this, create a perspectiveProjection for your shape:

```
_eventParent.transform.perspectiveProjection = new PerspectiveProjection();
```

PerspectiveProjection is located in the flash.geom package, so don't forget to import it.

Then whenever you update your shape's position, update it's vanishing point:

```
_eventParent.transform.perspectiveProjection.projectionCenter = 
    new Point(_eventParent.x, _eventParent.y);
```

You might need to offset the vanishing point by a set number of pixels to get the perspective looking the way you want it to.

Comment: Wow this sounds like a great solution, i will test next monday and give you the tick if its correct. :) Thanks very much anyway!!

Comment: HI bwroga, _eventParent.transform.perspectiveProjection = new PerspectiveProjection(); happen after mouseDown?

Comment: @bluebill1049 I would set it when you create _eventParent and set the projectionCenter for the first time then too. That way there won't be any weird jumps in perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I misunderstood your question. Your question is that if you apply rotation to the movieClip object, then why does the size appear to be changing?

For simplification, Let's not apply rotation on both X and Y axis. Let's take a rectangular movie clip and onMouseMove we do `++myMovieClip.rotationX`;

Now, this statement is going to apply rotation on the object about the X-axis and one would get a perspective of the movie clip flipping across X -axis and this flipping will show as change in size of the object.

The same applies to rotating across y-axis.

Comment: Hi abhinav, the rotationX and rotationY works great. my question is after you apply rotationX and rotationY of the sprite or movieClip. Try to start around the sprite or movieClip. you will see the item skew perspectily as you mouse move instead of remain the same rotationX and rotationY.