# setting new Y axis in as3

Tags: actionscript-3

Ok lets say i have image and i want to rotate it along Y axis. Problem is i need to move my Y axis so rotation would be proper. I do my work in pure as3 code so this trick needs to be done in pure as3 code, so no flash drawing tools available :( .
here some images that may help you

[image]

[image]

LATEST EDIT: problem is solved with ez then i found that as3 actually also have 4x4 matrices that called  Matrix3D  in documentation , so now it possible to do  all 3d rotations.

Comment: Please give a proper explanation. What rotation are you talking about and why do you have to change the y axis? So far, this question is unclear to me.

Comment: So are you looking to horizontal flip the image?

Comment: yes i looking for horizontal rotation.

Comment: perhaps you need to look at rotationX and rotationY, here is some useful info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15014581/as3-sprite-rotationx-and-rotationy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your question without a code example is very hard. As I can see, your local position of the figure is somewhat different from what you intend it to be to rotate as desired.

Generally spoken, there are two potential issues to solve:

1. You may adjust your image's x and y values so that the image is always drawn as desired. So you need to add/remove an offsetX and offsetY variable to all your drawings of your image to fine-adjust it's local position.
2. If you use a rotation function with a matrix you should beware of the correct sequence. Rotation applies differently either when you apply translation before or after it.

Hope this may help you. If you want a more specific answer, you need to provide some code exampple.